# How to put a vertical line to visually separate between two frames in Openoffice writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer, border

I tried to use with and without a third frame and then try to find the option of a vertical bar, but I could not. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can **insert a horizontal rule** using the **Menu**: Select Menu `Insert` -> `Horizontal Rule...`.

Alternatively, you could **use paragraph styles**:

1. Select the paragraph between the two frames and open the paragraph style options (using Menu `Format` -> `Paragraph...` or the context menu: right-click and select `Paragraph...`).
2. In the paragraphy style options, select the `Border` tab (1) and add a bottom border by clicking in the `User-defined Line arrangement` area as illustrated (2):

[image: Paragraph styles]

Finally, you could just modify one of the two frames and add a border at the frame's bottom or top respectively.